# Looking for title of a book in Linear Algebra I found on the web

Tags: linear-algebra

I found a link to a copy of few pages from a book in Linear Algebra. I couldn't find its title on the web. Does anybody know the title of this book?

The link is

www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math411/nation1

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the required reading for that course? http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~erik/course/hawaii/f03/411/index.html. It's not Kunze, but could be Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right.

Comment: @Moo: thanks for your reply. I thought it would be fast to get answer here. I would ask .

Comment: @kbau: thanks for the reply. It is not "Linear Algebra Done Right".

Comment: Perhaps it is Strang's linear algebra.